# Converse: $f'(x)\ge 0 \implies f$ is monotonically increasing?

Tags: real-analysis

In my textbook the following theorem is stated: If $f'(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$ then $ f $ is monotonically increasing.

Is the converse also true? Intuitively it seems like it is but I know there must be a reason why it's not an if and only if statement.

Comment: The converse is sort of the definition of monotonically increasing isn't it? "If $f$ is monotonically increasing then $f'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$"

Comment: The converse is false since $f$ might not be differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Comment: @D.W.: "Monotonic increasing" means that $f(x) \geq f(y)$ for $x \geq y$. It makes sense even for functions that aren't differentiable.

Comment: Indeed, even for functions that aren’t continuous.

Comment: I would recommend accepting Mark Joshi's answer unless you're not yet satisfied with the current responses.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is differentiable and monotone increasing then $f'(x) \geq 0.$

We prove this by contrapositive. if $x < y $ and $f(x) > f(y)$ then the mean-value theorem states, there exists $z \in (x,y)$ such that
$$
f'(z) = \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} < 0. 
$$
We are done.

Comment: Shouldn't contraposition/contrapositve in this case start with f'<0? Then apply the mean value theorem from which we can then conclude (as y>x and f'<0) that f(x) > f(y).

Answer (score 1):

The converse is true if, for example, you assume $f'$ is continuous away from a discrete set of points. If $f'(x_0)<0$, then continuity implies that $f'(x)<0$ on some interval around $x_0$. Then $f$ is decreasing on that interval.

Comment: But that last part is exactly what you're trying to prove (well, with $f$ replaced by $-f$).

Comment: Who said $f'$ was continuous?

Comment: @TedShifrin: Good point. Certainly can fail if $f'$ is not continuous near $x_0$.

Comment: @anomaly: Is this an objection? Perhaps you can elaborate.

Comment: @squirrel: I thought you were talking about the original statement rather than its converse. My fault, what you wrote is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The converse is true if you assume your function is differentiable; this is easily checked by writing down the limit definition of the derivative and using the fact that $f$ is monotone to establish the inequality on the derivative. Probably the reason why they didn't state the converse was that monotone functions need not be differentiable everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

To add explicitness to what everyone else is already stating. Take $f(x) = x \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\{x\leq 1\}} + (2x-1) \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\{x>1\}}$ then $f$ is monotonically increasing, yet $f'(1)$ is not defined.

Now, adding differentiability gives you a completely different story (see any of the other answers).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb  R$ is right differentiable and $f_+'(a) < 0$ then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $x \in [a,b]$, $$a< x < a+\delta \implies f(x) <f(a)$$

This comes from

$$x \in [a,b], a< x< a + \delta \implies \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x -a } < 0 \implies f(x) < f(a)$$

Just suppose for a moment that $f'(x) < 0$ for some $x \in [a,b]$, and get to a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

claim: differentiable function $f: \Re\rightarrow\Re$ is monotonically increasing $\Rightarrow$ $f'(x)\geq0$ for all x. (note that in here, the premiss have to state that $f$ is differentiable so that this proof can hold)

proof:

let $x_0 \in \Re $ be given.

then $x>x_0 \Rightarrow f(x)-f(x_0) \geq 0 \ $

and $x<x_0 \Rightarrow f(x)-f(x_0) \leq 0 \ $ since f is monotinally increasing.

since $f$ is differentiable, then, in both cases, the limit exists and  $\ \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\geq 0 \ $

that is, $f'(x)\geq0$